# Firebase realtime database: post query problem

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

I use Postman to test the following code.
The insertion is going well but the server sends me back: ***Error: could not handle the request***

```
exports.insertMesure = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    const identifiant = req.body.identifiant;
    const temperatureAir = req.body.temperatureAir;
    const humiditeSol = req.body.humiditeSol;
    const humiditeAir = req.body.humiditeAir;
    const niveauEau = req.body.niveauEau;
    const phSol = req.body.phSol;

    const mesure = {
        temperatureAir: temperatureAir,
        humiditeSol: humiditeSol,
        humiditeAir: humiditeAir,
        niveauEau: niveauEau,
        phSol: phSol
    };

    const dbRef = admin.database().ref('/users/' + identifiant + '/mesures');
    dbRef.push(mesure)
    .then(snapchot => {
        return snapchot;
    })
    .catch(err => {
        res.send('Error: ' + err);
    });
});
```

I send the following data with Postman:

```
{
    "identifiant": "talla",
    "temperatureAir": 45,
    "humiditeSol": 23,
    "humiditeAir": 106,
    "niveauEau": 55,
    "phSol": 6
}
```

Help me please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your server-side script is not sending anything back to the caller. You probably want to send back a status code to indicate the database write was completed successfully:

```
const dbRef = admin.database().ref('/users/' + identifiant + '/mesures');
dbRef.push(mesure)
  .then(snapshot => {
    res.status(200).send('ok');
  })
  .catch(err => {
    res.status(500).send(err);
  });
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I did as you say but I get the error:  error  Each then() should return a value or throw  promise/always-return

Comment: There is no `forEach` in the snippet I shared, so it seems unlikely that is causes that error. If you're having a new problem, either update your question with the latest code, or open a new question for the new problem.